# Export C# class as a COM class with a different name

Tags: c#, com, interop

I have an existing C# assembly I need to make it COM visible and also implementing a specific COM interface which I can't change.

One of the classes in the assembly has the same name as one of the coclasses in the IDL document (they're not the same class).
As I don't want (or can't) rename either, and I don't want to make the C# class a merge of its own functionality and the coclass functionality, I thought of making a different class (with a different name) and exporting it to COM with the original name.
Is it possible to export a C# class as a COM class with a custom name?

Something like:

```
[ComVisible(false)]
class Animal {} // original C# class

[ComCustomName("Animal")]
class ComAnimal {} // Com export
```

(The question is whether or not ComCustomNameAttribute exists)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is ProgIdAttribute what you're looking for?

Comment: Or rather CoClassAttribute

Comment: @Joe Both doesn't seem to work

Comment: .NET is not a .tlb/idl general generator. You cannot build a .NET class that "conforms" to an .idl coclass, aka: what would be the purpose of such an idl if it's implemented by .NET? Sounds like the XY problem https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @SimonMourier There is a legacy COM Object implementing a certain interface. A .Net assembly was written to replace the COM object. Now that .Net assembly needs to be used by some parts of the system which remained in COM. For that it needs to be COM visible and also retain the exact same COM interface to avoid re-compilation (The COM interface I need to replicate was given to me as an IDL file)

Comment: Yes, that makes senses, but you seem to be confusing coclass with interface. From a given IDL you can implement an interface defined in it in .NET. Also in .NET you can reuse the same CLSID (GuidAttribute) and the Progid (ProgIdAttribute) if necessary (depends on your COM client if it cannot be changed). But the coclass name is irrelevant here.